# Android 4.4 API 19 LocationListener onLocationChanged never fired but locationManager.getLastKnownLocation is updated

Tags: gps, android-4.4-kitkat, locationmanager, locationlistener

New to android... I am using Android Studio 1.0.2 with API 19 KitKat emulator (and project) to test gps handling... (also tested on phone with same results)

Thank you for any help! :)

telnet --> geo fix 24 24 does change locationManager.getLastKnownLocation! but does not fire onlocationchanged? (i never get the "triggered" log in the logcat where the getlastknownlocation is logged)

output: Latitude: 24.0. Longitude: 24.0. Provided by: gps at 1423821600000
(I know i need formatted date instead of gettime(), more worried about onlocationchanged at the moment)...

I have taken other debugging steps... the locationManager.getLastKnownLocation().getprovider() is gps... i hardcoded that into the locationmanager provider to test different things and that seems to be the problem most people had when i googled this (using network_service instead of gps when geo fix uses gps)...

every tutorial I have seen has been an intentservice or activity that implements locationListener, but I want the location listener peeled out separately... maybe that isn't possible or maybe just the emulator is having a problem?

I create a class and pass it the Context(Intent)

```
public class TestGPS{

    private Context context;
    private MyLocationListener locationListener;
    private LocationManager locationManager;

    public TestGPS(Context callingContext) { 
        this.context = callingContext;

        // Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
        this.locationManager = (LocationManager) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Define a listener that responds to location updates
        this.locationListener = new MyLocationListener(this.context, locationManager);
    }
```

this class requests new gps coordinates with

```
public void doStuff(){
    String provider = null;
    boolean gpsEnabledLocation = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    boolean networkEnabledLocation = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    if (networkEnabledLocation)
    {
        provider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
    }
    else if (gpsEnabledLocation)
    {
        provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
    }
        this.locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 0, this.locationListener);

    while (!this.locationListener.Triggered)
    {
        Location lastLocation = this.locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        if (lastLocation != null) {
            String lastLocationString = "Latitude: " + lastLocation.getLatitude() + ". Longitude: " + lastLocation.getLongitude() + ". Provided by: " + lastLocation.getProvider() + " at " + lastLocation.getTime();
            Log.i("locationManager", lastLocationString);
        }

        Thread.sleep(5 * 1000);
    }

    this.locationManager.removeUpdates(this.locationListener);
}
```

then the class that implements locationlistener

```
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    public boolean Triggered = false;

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.i("onLocationChanged", "Triggered");
        this.Triggered = true;
    }

    ... the other 3 functions
}
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Just hooked it up to my phone and got same results... it isn't an emulator problem the phone used network provider but getLastKnownLocation was update while onlocationchanged was never called

Comment: See my answer here for that:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28502513/how-get-the-current-latitud-and-longitud-without-use-getlastknownlocation-method/28502691#28502691